# Mac OS High Sierra: Running apt install bindfs returns error from Java

Tags: java, android, bash, android-ndk, apt

I have /usr/bin set as a $PATH variable, which is where 'apt' and 'install' both reside, yet Terminal is returning this...

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

whenever I run it.

I've tried cd to the /usr/bin directory, and double checked that the PATH exists in .bash_profile, and restarted the Terminal and tried again. Does this command need to exist in both locations, or do I need to somehow link the two locations?

I'm setting up a build environment for Android Go Language at the root of my $HOME folder. The environment is meant to support the release Soong.

Comment: This reminds me a lot of https://xkcd.com/1084

Comment: If only it were as simple... Atleast the ls command worked for her... I think I may have found something though. I reinstalled macports, and it seems to work for the most part.